# Efficient storage of inconsistent, relational foreign data?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am attempting to compress duplicates in semi-inconsistent data for better user experience and storage. Due to some natural (and important) inconsistency, combining entries may require an additional table to prevent loss of data. Additionally, a unique identifier must be made so the same (previously squashed) entries are not pulled down again. What is the best way to represent this on a relational database?

## Context:

I am currently designing an application that takes information available on a dining hall menu (json format) and makes it rate-able for the user so they are notified when their favorite items are available. I was successful at directly extracting this data in-app, but eventually realized that the source had a bit of inconsistency between naming and ids, so that the same item (Burger, or Char-grilled Burger) at two dining halls would appear twice (sometimes different names). As such, I decided to create a database that would allow me to edit entries so the user would only have to rate once for both items.

## Problem:

### Tables:

What I eventually realized was that, due to the inconsistencies in the table, two separate items (food) would link to two different serving locations (courses), each at different dining halls (meal). For example, Burgers and Char-grilled Burger are stored as two separate rows even though they are identical aside from the name and the dining hall they are served at. When trying to combine two separate food items into one using my current schema, one of the serving locations would be lost. It is possible that I could introduce another column, but this is not good for scaling to additional dining halls or for memory use(as most items will  have the same location *consistently* between dining halls ~ like burgers at the grill). I also thought about adding some kind of intermediary table, but I am not sure how to go about doing so without being redundant or taking up too much space. I also believe that the location - time combination in Meal must remain as the dining halls can close at different times. Additionally, since the items are being renamed, I must have some sort of unique identifier to prevent storing the original item again(outside data has ids but these are unique to each of the differently named items).

Current Schema:

1. Calendar

   - Links a date with the Meal and Food item
   - Example: On 07/07/2017, Cinnamon Rolls will be served at Breakfast @ South
   - Fields: `date, meal, food`
2. Meal

   - Refers to the particular time and place the meal is served
   - Example: Breakfast @ South, Dinner @ North
   - Fields: `id, name, location, starttime, endtime`
3. Food

   - Information about a particular food item
   - Example: Cinnamon Roll, Burger, *Char-grilled Burger*
   - Fields: `id, name, nutritionurl, course`
4. Course

   - Refers to what section of the dining hall the item is served at
   - Example: Grill Station, Salad Bar, *SDH Grill*
   - Fields: `name`

Calendar has many rows but only stores information a week in advance, while the others contain cumulative data (food items will be added once they appear on the menu for the first time).

Example data input (from source):

- "White Dinner Rolls" (Food, outside id: 57) are at "South Dining Hall" at "Dinner" (Meal) at the "SDH Grill" (Course) on a particular day
- "Dinner Rolls" (Food, outside id:56) are at "North Dining Hall" at "Dinner" (Meal) at the "Salad Bar" (Course) on a particular day (could be same)

For my database, I would try and compress the two dinner roll entries as one food, but then with the current schema, one of the courses would be lost. Similarly, I also need to compress some of the Course entries as they specify the dining hall, even when both have the same section ("Grill" vs "SDH Grill").

### How my question is different:

There may be a similar answer but my search has been unsuccessful so far (not sure about keywords to look for). As opposed to many others, my question relates specifically to the relationship between tables *and* how to efficiently work with semi-inconsistent data.

Comment: Forget transforming/"compressing" to a new design. Find some design(s) that record the situations you have. That will reflect old tables & add new ones, maybe reuse. But you will not be restricted by having to describe/conceptualize/vary a design in terms of *changes* to an old one. PS Forget constraints. They collectively characterize possible situations/states. Find each needed *predicate*--a statement template parameterized by column names, made into statement by a row--each gets a table. Predicates & possible situations determine constraints. Which are for error prevention not querying.

Comment: PS Consider your poetic term "semi-inconsistent". That's the (semi-inconsistent?) point of view of the 1st design. Simply describing what *is*, there's a relationship/association on items & names captured by predicate "item I is called N in some hall" which happens to be 1:many in I:N. Although even if instead the same item could be called by different names *and/or* different items could be called by the same name *the queries for rows with given predicates are the same*. No poets need apply. [How do I model *(some stuff or other)* relationally?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42289340/3404097)